# Segment objects after extracting feature points using fast(Opencv)

Tags: computer-vision

I have this code where i managed to extract features using fast and then track those points using Lucas kanade method but now I want to segment and draw a bounding box around each object in the video. Any ideas will be appreciated. Thanks in advance. This is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/video/tracking.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    bool addRemovePt = false;
    VideoCapture cap;
    TermCriteria termcrit(TermCriteria::COUNT | TermCriteria::EPS, 20, 0.03);
    Size subPixWinSize(10, 10), winSize(31, 31);
    cap.open(0);
    if (!cap.isOpened())
        return -1;
    namedWindow("Video", 1);
    float scalingFactor = 0.75;
    Mat gray, prevGray, image, frame;
    bool init = true;
    vector<Point2f> Points[2];
    int count = 0;
    while (true) {
        cap >> frame; // capture frame from webcam
        if (frame.empty())
            break;
        resize(frame, frame, Size(), scalingFactor, scalingFactor, INTER_AREA);
        frame.copyTo(image);
        cvtColor(image, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY); // change to grayscale
        if (init) {
            vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1;
            Ptr<FastFeatureDetector> fastDetector = FastFeatureDetector::create(20);
            fastDetector->detect(gray, keypoints_1); // detect interest points using fast every 30 frames
            KeyPoint::convert(keypoints_1, Points[1]);
            init = false;
        }
        else if (!Points[0].empty()) {
            vector<uchar> status;
            vector<float> err;

            if (prevGray.empty()) {
                gray.copyTo(prevGray);
                cout << "once" << endl;
            }
            // Lucas-kannade optical flow
            calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prevGray, gray, Points[0], Points[1], status, err, winSize, 3, termcrit, 0, 0.001);
            size_t i, k;
            for (i = k = 0; i < Points[1].size(); i++)
            {
                if (!status[i])
                    continue;
                Points[1][k++] = Points[1][i];
                circle(image, Points[1][i], 3, Scalar(0, 255, 0), -1, 8);
            }
            Points[1].resize(k);
        }

        imshow("Video", image);
        count++;
        if (count == 15) {
            count = 0;
            init = true;
        }
        if (waitKey(30) >= 0)
            break;
        swap(Points[1], Points[0]);
        swap(prevGray, gray);
    }
    cap.release();
    return 0;
}
```

[This is what i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6V1xh.jpg)

[This is what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zG01j.jpg)

Comment: can you show images with your input and outputs, preferably showing what results you are trying to achieve. Right now it is not clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: what I am trying to accomplish is, I have a live video feed which is dynamic(in motion). I want identify all objects in the video , draw a bounding box around on each object and track them in real time. I have added a picture example.

Comment: do you know the objects initial location/position at a first frame?

Comment: On the first frame I ran the FAST corner detector and get the interest points.  Then I use lucas kanade to track those points. I don't know what you mean by the position of the objects? Did u see the pictures I posted on top.  This is what I have and This is what I want are links to the pictures.

Comment: it sounds like you are asking how to classify objects given corners locations, is that correct? Do you know which objects you will be trying to identify?

Comment: All objects but I don't need to know what the objects are. I tried K-means clustering to group interest points together but the background is to noisy.

Comment: gotcha, I think your problem is too generic. I would use divide and conquer approach. Start by defining the smallest/simplest version of what you are trying to accomplish and know how to do and then expand on it.